# Win 11 access denied between networked computers

Tags: networking, printer, network-shares, windows-11

I have 2 Dell XPS desktop computers (both 8940) running Win 11, connected by ethernet with a router - Wi-Fi is turned off on both computers. File Explorer on both computers lists mypc1 and mypc2 under “Network”, and clicking on the local one shows the shared resources but clicking on the networked one says “Access Denied - you may not have permission to use this resource.”  All of the GUI dialogs for accessing a network shared resource fail in this manner.  I need to have a folder on each computer that can be accessed as a shared resource on the other.  The normal GUI way to map a shared resource fails. I also need to share a printer that is  physically attached to mypc1 - on mypc2 as a network printer.  Again the normal GUI dialogs fail with access denied.

I have used this arrangement for years with Dell XPS desktops running Win 10 with zero problems.  The problem started after I upgraded one desktop to Win 11 and replaced the other with a new Dell that came with Win 11 already installed.

I’ve spent many hours reviewing all the network sharing settings, performing all the upgrades, and running both Dell and Windows diagnostics.  The Dell diagnostics find no problems.  The windows diagnostics did detect a network issue but said it didn’t have enough information and offered no help.

I’ve turned off the password requirement in the Network Profile.  I’ve turned on the discovery options.

I’m signed on, in identical fashion, onto both computers as administrators per my Microsoft account.

I’ve tried everything with my virus protection firewalls turned off.

I’ve tried to use Credentials with no success either - same access denied errors

I have been able to connect the shared folders with Power Shell - but no luck with the printer sharing.

Some Power Shell command results:

When run on both mypc1 and mypc2:
Net View shows the names of my two computers mypc1 and mypc2

When run from either computer, the following commands are successful to map [or remove] a network shared folder:
New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\mypc[1 or 2]\DataTransferFolder" -Persist
Remove-PSDrive -Name T

When run on mypc1 to see if the physically connected shared printer shows up:

Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Share" | FT
It successfully shows my shared printer on mypc1 where the physical printer is attached

When the following is run on mypc2 trying to connect to the shared printer on mypc1:
Get-Printer -ComputerName mypc1 | where Shared -eq $true | fl Name
I get the error “Access was denied to the specified resource”

- CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) Get-Printer], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Get-Printer

Other than some limited success with Power Shell, I can’t get past the basic problem that the two computers have a “Permissions'' issue.  I’m asking for help regarding anything else that might need to be diagnosed or adjusted.  At this point the mapped drives work for the folder sharing but I have no solution for printer sharing - unless I buy a USB switch to cable the printer to both computers - like I did 20 years ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of following numerous procedures for network, security, permissions, hardware, etc, to diagnose or fix my issue - nothing worked.  And, I could find no other suggestions from Microsoft, Dell, Tech sites, etc.

Finally, it dawned on me that I was using 2 step verification on my Microsoft account that is use to sign onto my computers.  This was the cause of the issue.  It can be turned off temporarily to make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check both machines and ensure both are set to Private Network.
Go Settings app then Network & internet / Ethernet and the setting is on that page.